# Will Google and other search engines follow IP address only sites (i.e., no URL)

Tags: search-engines, ip-address, web-crawlers

Will Google and other search engines follow links to and index sites that don't have a URL, but instead just use their IP address's (obviously they would need a unique IP) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For years, I haven't seen a site ranking in Google that doesn't have a domain name.  That doesn't mean it isn't possible, but few (if any) sites are doing that now.  Here are a bunch of reasons that you should get a domain name:

- IP addresses cannot be moved from one web host to another the way that domain names can.

  - IP Addresses change.  It is very difficult to obtain a IP address that can be stable for a number of years.  Most ISPs force IP address changes from time to time.  Heck, your ISP may even go out of business.
  - You may *want* to change IP address, for example to move to a better host.
- Domain names are cheap

  - You can get `.com` for around $10/year.
  - You can get free third level domain names (for example from dyndns)
- Domain names give you branding.  You don't want to brand yourself to an IP address, but you do want to choose a domain name that is brandable.
- A domain name is reputable.  Even if you can get an IP address site ranked in Google, it will be harder to rank well than with a domain name.  Google may see the domain name as a quality signal.  Even if Google doesn't explicitly have a ranking factor for it, users will trust a URL with a domain name more which can have an indirect impact on your rankings.
- A domain name is memorable.  Who is going to want to rememeber and type in an IP address?

Comment: Google regularly crawls & indexes content under IP addresses, but like you mentioned, there's almost no reason to aim for that. I'd personally also avoid using third-level domains and instead try to get a "real" domain name of your own (that you can control as you want to).